# he.decode in polymer framework is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polymer, decode

I am trying to decode the messagetext in polymer javascript framework with the help of bower component he.js. But, it's not going in the right way as I think so.

```
 <script src="../bower_components/he/he.js"></script>

    <dom-module id="mesages">
      <template>        

      <vaadin-grid items="[[messages]]">

      <vaadin-grid-column flex="0">
        <template class="header">Message</template>
        <template>[[item.messagetext]]</template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>
    </vaadin-grid>
    </template>   

      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'mesages',
          properties: {

            uname: {
              type: String,
              value: ""
            },

            messages: Object,

            qParams: {
              type: Object,
              value: null,
            },
          },

            lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                this.showMessage('Error in getting messages ' + err);
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
              } else {
                try {
                  console.log("Successfully got the messages " + data);
                  var retObj = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
                  if ((retObj.error === undefined) && (retObj.errorMessage === undefined)) {
                    this.messages = retObj.item;
                    console.log(this.messages);   
                   for(i=0;i<this.messages.length;i++){           

                    this.messages[i].messagetext=he.decode(this.messages[i].messagetext);


                     console.log(this.messages[i].messagetext);                    
                     console.log(this.messages[i].messageid);
                     console.log(this.messages[i].userid);  

                   }
                  } else {
                    this.showMessage("Error in getting the messages " + retObj.error);
                    return;
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log("Error in getting the messages " + e);
                }
              }
              this.fire('iron-signal', {
                name: 'pg-load-indicator-record',
                data: {
                  "event": "Messages"
                }
              });
            }.bind(this));
          },

        })
      </script>

    </dom-module>
```

Still getting the encoded output given below on the screen instead of decoded one:

```
&#x3C;p&#x3E;simple test on message display
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t directly import js files. What you have to do is to create another html file which contains

```
//hejs-import.html
<script src="../bower_components/he/he.js"></script>
```

And then import that html in your component which then makes the js file availible in your component

```
//messages.html
<link rel="import" href="hejs-import.html">
```

Comment: I have rectified it.The problems is I was trying to display the decoded text before running the JavaScript.